# query to count number of values that is stored in one field of column in sql

Tags: postgresql, count

i have one table name as technician and the columns in this able is SQUAD and INDIVISUAL.

The record of this table is as follows:

```
SQUAD      | andheri 2(Pradeep Bhikaji Mohite,Amol Sopan Auti)
INDIVIDUAL | 0
```

now i want my output should be look like:

```
SQUAD      | andheri 2(Pradeep Bhikaji Mohite,Amol Sopan Auti)
INDIVIDUAL | 2
```

that is,in INDIVISUAL column the value should be the count of names that is their into SQUAD column. which means in my SQUAD column there is two name  Pradeep Bhikaji Mohite and Amol Sopan Auti,so the count of values that is thier into SQUAD column should come into INDIVISUAL.

Please help me to come out of this problem and send me the solution as soon as possibe..
Awaiting for your reply

Comment: Is the list of names always between parentheses?

Comment: This is a **really** bad data model. You should read up on database normalization.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the number of names based on number of occurrence of COMMA.

```
SELECT (LEN(SQUAD)-LEN(REPLACE(SQUAD,',',''))+1 AS INDIVIDUAL
FROM table_name
```

Hope this should solve your problem.